# Jquery Ajax Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created a helper function that builds the list items for a carousel. Ideally I would call this at the bottom of the page and output the html structure on the page. It should receive a url and then fetch the data from the passed url.

Could someone enlighten me as to why the following function is not returning the value to the page?

**Javascript**

```
function selectAfterCharacter(item, character) {
    return item.substring(item.lastIndexOf(": ") + 1, item.length).trim();
}


function buildCarouselItem (url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(result) {
            html = jQuery(result);
            var title = (html.find("h1#product_title").html());
            var productId = (html.find("span#prod_code").html());
            var strippedId = selectAfterCharacter(productId, ": ");

            var price = (html.find("span.one_price").html());
            var Nowprice = (html.find("span.now_price").html());


            if (price !== undefined) {
               var price = (html.find("span.one_price").html());
            } else {
                var price = (html.find("span.now_price").html());
            }

            return(` 
                <li>
                    <a href='${url}'>
                        <img alt='${title}' src='http://www.awebsite.com/${strippedId}/large/${strippedId}.jpg'>
                        <div class="product-title">
                            ${title}
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-price">
                            <h4>${price}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                `
            );  
        },
    });
};

function buildCompleteCarousel (theArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length ;  i++) {
        buildCarouselItem(theArray[i]);
    }
}

var LinksArray = [
    "http://www.awebsite.com/115812",
    "http://www.awebsite.com/115812",
    "http://www.awebsite.com/115812"
];

var htmlOutput = buildCompleteCarousel(LinksArray);

$('output').innerHTML = htmlOutput;
```

Comment: Because you can not return from ajax, you need to use promise or callback function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can't return anything from a function that is asynchronous. What you can return is a promise or you can use `callback` function like this:

```js
function selectAfterCharacter(item, character) {
  return item.substring(item.lastIndexOf(": ") + 1, item.length).trim();
}

function buildCarouselItem(url, callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(result) {
      var html = jQuery(result);
      var title = (html.find("h1#product_title").html());
      var productId = (html.find("span#prod_code").html());
      var strippedId = selectAfterCharacter(productId, ": ");
      var price = (html.find("span.one_price").html());
      var Nowprice = (html.find("span.now_price").html());
      if (price !== undefined) {
        price = (html.find("span.one_price").html());
      } else {
        price = (html.find("span.now_price").html());
      }
      var returnVal = "<li>\
                <a href='${url}'>\
                        <img alt='${title}' src='http://www.awebsite.com/${strippedId}/large/${strippedId}.jpg'>\
                        <div class='product-title'>\
                            ${title}\
                        </div>\
                        <div class='product-price'>\
                        <h4>${price}</h4>\
                        </div>\
                        </a>\
                        </li>";
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(returnVal);
      }
    }
  });
}

function buildCompleteCarousel(theArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    buildCarouselItem(theArray[i], function(response) {
      $('output').append(response);
    });
  }
}
var LinksArray = [
  "http://www.awebsite.com/115812",
  "http://www.awebsite.com/115812",
  "http://www.awebsite.com/115812"
];
buildCompleteCarousel(LinksArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function buildCarouselItem (url) {
var myHTML = '';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        html = jQuery(result);
        var title = (html.find("h1#product_title").html());
        var productId = (html.find("span#prod_code").html());
        var strippedId = selectAfterCharacter(productId, ": ");

        var price = (html.find("span.one_price").html());
        var Nowprice = (html.find("span.now_price").html());


        if (price !== undefined) {
           var price = (html.find("span.one_price").html());
        } else {
            var price = (html.find("span.now_price").html());
        }

        myHTML = ` 
            <li>
                <a href='${url}'>
                    <img alt='${title}' src='http://www.awebsite.com/${strippedId}/large/${strippedId}.jpg'>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        ${title}
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <h4>${price}</h4>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            `;
        );  
    },
});
return myHTML ;
};

function buildCompleteCarousel (theArray) {
    var HTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length ;  i++) {
        HTML += buildCarouselItem(theArray[i]);
    }
    return HTML;
}
```

The important part is un jQuery.ajax : "async : false".
So the function will wait for ajax to return the html

.

Comment: Never recommend `async: false`. it's deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the information.